# ACR122 - Android / How to get the UID's

Tags: android, nfc, acr122

I try to integrate an ACR122 to my android app. I'm using the ANDROID Library (http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/) available on ACS.

Everything work, I can detect the presence of a card but I want to keep the UID/ID of the card.

Do you have an example of this type of integration ?

Thank you

Comment: You can try to extract the UID into an .sqlite database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I misspoke I'm not want to keep but I want to retrieve in the Library the UID. :)

Comment: You should add the tag [tag:android] or no one will answer it. I have no idea how to use it as well. But you also should update the question to reflect that you want to extract the UID, instead of keeping it (that will be interpreted as saving the UID in a database).

Comment: Is there a reason whay you asked this exact same question twice (other one here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29817873/2425802)? If you want to edit your question use the *edit* link below it.